# How to prevent AJAX server side transmission?

Tags: php, ajax, abort, transmission

Not asking how to abort AJAX.

In this case, does anyone know how to prevent the server from transmitting?

For example, in dynamic pagination, a user may scroll 1 line at a time rapidly, causing many requests.

This can easily be cancelled on client-side jQuery with `abort`, but for those of us pinching pennies on bandwidth allocation, how can we keep the previous requests from transmitting when a new one has been received?

Many thanks in advance!

**Specifics**

Actually, it's because I'm using the jQuery UI Slider, and I've set the `slide` event to hit the server.

As you might expect, if you slide that sucker 10% across, the server's just been hit like crazy and is still transmitting all that data even though I've `abort`ed.

That's the true source of the problem since just hitting the up or down button fast probably (in my mind) can't be stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'm overthinking it.

In the dynamic pagination case, I think I can set a `$_SESSION` equal to `microtime(true)` at the very beginning of the php and also hold it in a variable.

Right before transmission (or any other resource intensive step) I can check to see if it's still equal.  If not, `exit`.

However, if anyone else can come up with the general purpose solution where you can allow multiple parallel requests, they get the check and +1 from me.

Comment: Have you already looked into http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php?

Comment: @RobW Ah, thank-you for the added knowledge!  Does jQuery's `ajax` send the required abort code?  Is the default PHP setting to `exit` (or equivalent) upon abort?  Thanks again!

Comment: You have to abort the request itself. To achieve that, you need to store the result of a  `$.ajax()` call somewhere, and call `.abort()` on it whenever you create a new request (provided that the variable exists). Whenever the request succeeds or fails, void the variable to free up resources.

Answer (score -1):

In this case you can consider using Server-sent events. This opens a persistent HTTP connection for transmitting data from server to client. This prevents the client to request data rapidly and waste bandwidth. An example code:

Server-side: (PHP)

```
<?php
@set_time_limit(0);
header('Content-type: text/event-stream');
header('Transfer-encoding: chunked');
while(true){
    echo 'data:'.$data."/n/n";//todo: send data here
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
?>
```

Client-side: (javascript)

```
var ev = new EventSource('path/to/script');
ev.onmessage = function(e){
    var data = e.data;
    //todo: handle data here
};
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: SSE are not supported in IE10, by the way. Besides, SSE does not solve the core problem, which is to detect when a request is aborted. http://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource

Comment: If you want the connection to be bi-directional, then you can use websocket but it's hard to set up in php.

Comment: But SSE can send data when necessary and it only uses a single connection.